# How to extract the entire path when a user uploads a file using jquery

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I am trying to extract the entire path of the file that a user uploads on the browser and this i need to do using javascript or jquery.

If i give `($("#userfile").val());` i am able to extract only the file name and not the entire path.

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it's a security measure to not reveal the entire path of file inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Internet explorer will give you the full path, but other browsers won't. [here's an example   page i found](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScriptDemo/FileUpload.htm) that demonstrates this

Comment: FF2 gives you the full path as well.

Answer (score 1):

With IE8 this is not the case too. IE8 hides the real path to the file and changes it, for example, to:

```
C:\\**fakepath**\filename
```

Answer (score 1):

as indicated above this is usually permission issue. try and and move the file to a different area and grant it full permissions.

```
var path = $('#file').attr("value");
```

this will also give you the path of the file