# Client Path of uploaded file or image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, path

It is possible to get the path of image path, when uploaded using file element?

Basically, I want to grab the clients path and show it on the page so that user can be certain of what image he chosed, before uploading it.

Any alternative suggestion are welcomed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract the entire path when a user uploads a file using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672357/how-to-extract-the-entire-path-when-a-user-uploads-a-file-using-jquery)

Comment: And Yes, this is a duplicate question, but the previous question is still left unsolved

Comment: it's "unsolved" for a reason, hint, hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its browser security -- you cannot get access to the full path on the user's filesystem. As a web-app, you only get access to the actual file and its name. Afaik, you can do this by writing a browser plugin, but with normal security privileges, you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

are you meaning you want to grab the image, or just grab the path?

if you want the path you could use: $('#uploadinput').val();

Comment: that only returns the file name the whole path. I want the whole path

Comment: THE PATH. I DEMAND THE PATH D<